# How to deploy my own Jar file in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

How can I deploy my own jar file into Artifactory. For example, I have my own plugin which requires to be uploaded/deployed as an artifact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do that - REST API and the UI.

1. REST API is what the build and dependency management tools use. You can use Maven, Gradle or whatever build tool you use to upload the artifacts. The easiest way to set up your build tool to work with Artifactory is using the Set Me Up button in Artifactory UI. Go to the artifact browser, select the repository you want to upload to, and hit the Set Me Up button for instructions.
2. You can upload a file using Artifactory UI. Go to the artifact browser, select the repository you want to upload to, and hit the Upload button for instructions. Generally it's a not scalable solution, but for one artifact it's fine.

Comment: Can you please help me here with my new query what are the best practices to deploy a JAR build with maven through jenkins in Artifactory?

Comment: I think for newer versions of Artifactory, that "Upload" button has been replaced by the "Deploy" button.